# Ranorex Automated Testing Tool Recording Issue with WPF Application

Tags: automated-tests

I have got huge wpf application for hosipital.Now we have decided to go with automated Testing Tool
I went through few tools and made some research and picked up few to implement it.Now Ranorex Tool is superb tool but there are only very few little demo videos for wpf were there.

My Requirement is to Test my wpf application fully automated and I should able to test the application through command Prompt.I have tried few tools I Strucked up

My existing Application functionality goes like this...
In my wpf application , the mainwindow consists many tiles . and each tile will have many imageicons while moving the mouse cursor onto the tile it zooms bigger then we can able to click on imageicon then it will navigate to other screen which I  can say popup window opens up and there we push some information and saves up then close the popup window.

When Recording through the **Ranorex Tool**,After clicking on ImageIcon of particular Tile it is not responding if anything there to setup please let me know I will be happy if any videos or screenshots step by step for WPF Automation is there

If any Automation Testing Tool with Good stuff Demo and video  Please let me Know

Thank You

Comment: I'm honestly not sure i understand your question.  It sounds like the problem you are having is that the test clicks a button and then if there is an automation for the next window the test freezes?

Comment: Hi thank you fast response Darse..you are close my problem,while recording the application when pop up window opens, it freezes